# Bash filename prefix replacement

Tags: linux, bash, shell, operators, filenames

I've read around, but I can't seem to wrap my head around this. I'm converting ripped files I made in flac to mp3 for a mp3 player. This set is from two CDs though, so their number prefix is undesirable.

Some filename examples:

```
01 Foo 9.flac
02 Foo 10.flac
03 Foo 11.flac
04 Foo 12.flac
05 Foo 13.flac
25 Foo 1.flac
26 Foo 2.flac
...
```

Here's what I have so far

```
$for file in *Foo*.flac; do flac -cd "$file" | lame -q 0 -V0 - "/media/mp3player/speech/${file%.flac}.mp3"; done
```

How can I go about removing the number and space prefix, and ideally replace it with what corresponds to the ending number?

So step in the right direction would be

From: 25 Foo 1

To: Foo 1

But this would be ideal

From: 25 Foo 1

To: 1 Foo 1

I've read through the Shell Parameter Expansion section of the Bash Reference Manual, but without examples, I'm having a hard time. I'll keep tinkering, but I wanted to post to see if anyone had any insight.

Comment: So what do you exactly want to do? Change from `NN Foo (M)*.flac` to `(M)* Foo (M)*.flac`

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a better version, but this should work:

```
for file in *Foo*.flac
do
  n=${file#*Foo} # erase from filename Foo and preceding characters
  n=${n%.flac}   # get file index
  fileout=${n}${file#[0-9]?}.mp3  #this works as long as you have two digits numbers only
  flac -cd "$file" | lame -q 0 -V0 - "/media/mp3player/speech/${fileout}.mp3"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{old=$0;a=$NF;gsub(".flac","",a);$1=a;new=$0;system("mv \""old"\" \""new"\"");}'
```

tested below:

```
> ls -1 01*
01 Foo 25.flac
01 Foo 26.flac
01 Foo 9.flac

> ls -1 01*| awk '{old=$0;a=$NF;gsub(".flac","",a);$1=a;new=$0;system("mv \""old"\" \""new"\"");}'

> ls -1 *.flac
25 Foo 25.flac
26 Foo 26.flac
9 Foo 9.flac
>
```